# Android device doesn't support Google Play Services

Tags: google-play-store, samsung, 4.2-jelly-bean, google-play-services

I'm using Samsung Galaxy Trend 3 SM-G3502U on Android 4.2.2.

Since this is a Chinese device, so it was normal to be shipped without GApps. So, I tried to install the latest version among the versions which are compatible with Android 4.2.2 of the following apps from APKMirror:

- Google Play Services
- Google Play Services Framework
- Google Calendar Sync
- Google Contacts Sync
- Google Account Manager

Still, no luck, since when I tried logging into Snapchat, a pop-up "popped" out, saying that Google Play Services is not supported by my device.

Also, when I installed and opened the latest version of Play Store among the compatible versions for Android 4.4.2 from APKMirror, it showed "Error retrieving information from server RH-01" which meant that I didn't have the compatible GApps installed.

Having all the apps listed above installed, I installed the "Device ID" app by Evozi. It couldn't show me the GSF. The space for that was left out empty instead.

Now, are there any more ways to try out for me so that my phone supports Google Services Framework, or I am left out with installing a custom ROM?

Comment: First, I wonder how those apps should work when installed as user apps, as several (if not all) of them require elevated permissions and thus must be installed as system apps. See e.g. [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](/q/27808/16575) [OpenGApps](https://opengapps.org/) might be worth a check as well, but make sure to read [their FAQ](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: I cannot find my android version on OpenGApps (4.2.2). So, will I have to install a custom rom?

Comment: Although I found one here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/boycracked.com/2017/05/24/official-gapps-for-android-4-2-2-jellybean-flashable-zip/amp/  it requires me to flash a custom recovery, for which I have to unlock the bootloader. But I'm not being able to find a suitable version of Odin for my device to do this. And also, some other tutorials do not guarantee their method for all samsung devices, like the one here:https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-unlock-bootloaders-on-Samsung-phones# . And most importantly, I cant find my device in the TWRP devices list

Comment: Sorry, but Android 4.2.2 (Jelly Bean) is ancient (2012/2013). The latest version is Android 8.1 currently, so you won't find much support for something that outdated (though you can check our [google-apps tag-wiki](/tags/google-apps/info) for some viable alternatives – and indeed, [TeamAndroid has some for 4.2](http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/)). And yes, to flash 3rd party stuff (Custom ROM) you'll need a custom recovery, which needs an unlocked bootloader.

Comment: Jelly bean Android devices are still supported by Google Play Services https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Jelly_Bean

Comment: If possible, check out the microg project https://microg.org/

Answer (score 1):

The `apk`s will not work without system libraries, and other frameworks that cannot be installed without root (or flushing from a recovery).